# Modify jQuery UI colorpicker slider to include black and white values

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, canvas, colors, html5-canvas

I'm currently using a modified version of the jQuery UI colorpicker slider, [see fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/t2PDc/10/). I'm wondering if there's an easy way to trick it so that when it's at value 0, the color will actually be black (#000, hsl(0, 0%, 0%)), and when it's to the max value of 360 it will instead turn white (#fff, hsl(360, 100%, 100%)). I'm not a js pro but I was thinking something along the lines of...

```
slide: function(event, ui) {
    if (ui.value = 0) $('#box').attr('data-color', 'hsl(' + ui.value + ', 0%, 0%)');
    box.style.background = 'hsl(' + ui.value + ', 100%, 50%)';
    var clr = $('#box').css('background-color');
    $('#box').attr('data-color', clr).trigger('click');
    $('#slider-handle').css('background-color', clr);
}
```

But this isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
    $("#slider-horiz").slider({
    orientation: "horizontal",
    min: 0,
    max: 360,
    value: 0,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        box.style.background = 'hsl(' + ui.value + ', 100%, 50%)';
        var clr = $('#box').css('background-color');
        $('#box').attr('data-color', clr).trigger('click');
        if (ui.value == 0) {
            $('#box').attr('data-color', 'hsl(' + ui.value + ', 0%, 0%)').trigger('click');
            $('#slider-handle').css('background-color', '#000');
        }
        if (ui.value == 360) {
            $('#box').attr('data-color', 'hsl(' + ui.value + ', 100%, 100%)').trigger('click');
            $('#slider-handle').css('background-color', '#fff');
        }


    }
});
```

});